# Indefinitely running code in separate Thread at particular interval iOS

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, swift, multithreading

> Objective

- Run a code indefinitely at a regular interval
- Using Thread
- Not using Timer

> A sample from Android would be like this

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (recordingState == STATE.RECORDING) {

                    System.out.println("Yay! we are still recording")

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000 / 12); //12 fps refresh rate
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

                    }
                }
            }
        };

thread.start();
```

*This code would run for 12 Frames per second till we are Recording.*

Something similar on **iOS** *(Swift)* can be achieved using **Timer** by *(scheduling at particular interval)* but is there anyway more similar to the above approach?

*Note: I don't have knowledge of Objective-C so, if you can please try answer in Swift, nevertheless all answers are welcome.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                        while self.recording{
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                print(":::> \(self.recorder?.currentTime)")
                            }
                            usleep(useconds_t(1e+6) / 30)    // sleep in milliseconds 30 fps
                        }
                    }
```

Damn it! Found the answer myself. The same approach worked here. The `sleep()` function consider the parameter in Seconds so, instead use `usleep()`.

Answer (score 1):

Code to run a timer in Infinite mode on Objective C

```
NSTimer  *timerRefresh;

 timerRefresh  = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void) timerFired{
}
```